# d3 choropleth map showing only one color

Tags: d3.js, join, colors, topojson, choropleth

I'm a noob. I joined a tsv file to Mike Bostock's topojson using d3.map(). The join works, if I console.log the keys, I can see the corresponding values. I put these in the attr("fill"...) thing. I use scaleThreshold and specify 5 items in the domain and 5 items in the range. However, the map only displays the features using the first color in the range, no matter how close the tsv value is to the highest or lowest numbers in the domain.

Here is the tsv showing only some of the rows but still displays the same issue.

```
GEOID   displaylabel    rate
01001   "Autauga County, Alabama"   55601
01003   "Baldwin County, Alabama"   218022
01005   "Barbour County, Alabama"   24881
01007   "Bibb County, Alabama"  22400
01009   "Blount County, Alabama"    57840
01011   "Bullock County, Alabama"   10138
01013   "Butler County, Alabama"    19680
01015   "Calhoun County, Alabama"   114277
01017   "Chambers County, Alabama"  33615
01019   "Cherokee County, Alabama"  26032
```

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

        <style>
           .county-borders {
                fill: none;
                stroke-width: 0.5px;
            }

            .counties {
                fill: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg height = "960" width = "1000"></svg>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            var svg = d3.select("svg");
            var path = d3.geoPath();

            var data = d3.map();

            var color = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain(0, 10000, 500000, 800000, 1000000)
                .range(["blue", "aqua", "purple", "indigo", "green"]);

            d3.queue()
                .defer(d3.json, "https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json")
                .defer(d3.tsv, "PEP_2018_PEPANNRES.tsv", function(d){
                data.set(d.GEOID, +d.rate);
                })
                .await(ready);

            //The syntax is this (error, deferVariable1, deferVariable2)
            function ready(error, us, tsv) {

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "counties")
                    .selectAll("path")
                    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
                    .enter()
                    .append("path")
                    .style("fill", function(d) {

                   //The join works          
                   console.log(data.get(d.id))

                        if (data.get(d.id)) {
                            return color(data.get(d.id));   
                        } else {
                            return "black";
                        }
                    })
                    .attr("d", path);

                //Draw the boundaries
                svg.append("path")
                    .attr("class", "county-borders")
                    .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, 
function(a, b){ return a !== b; })));


        }; 


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your color scale domain needs to be an array.

Comment: Right on. You did it. I changed the domain to look like this .domain([0, 10000, 500000, 800000, 1000000]). It worked.